# Hashmap to JSON Array

Tags: android, arrays, hashmap

I would like to ask if someone here knows how to convert a HashMap to JSON Array to be used on a Adapter. The logic is when you logged in, it will fetch data on a web server using Volley, store it on SQLite database and at the same time it will show the retrieve data on a custom listview. The thing is, if you will move to another fragment on the application and then go back, it will request again on the volley which it will take time. I wanted that if you will go back the data stored on the SQLite database will be retrieved and if the user wanted to update the data using SwipeRefresh, that's the time to update for new data.

Here is my code.

```
public void LoadMarkets()
{
    Map<String,String>tmpRate = new HashMap<String,String>();

    RateDb db = new RateDb(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Cursor rs = db.getData();
    if(rs!=null && rs.getCount()>0)
    {
        if(rs.moveToFirst())
        {
            while(rs.moveToNext())
            {
                tmpRate.put("rateID",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateID)));
                tmpRate.put("Name",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateName)));
                tmpRate.put("Rate",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateRate)));
                tmpRate.put("Date",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateDate)));
                tmpRate.put("Time",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateTime)));
                tmpRate.put("Ask",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateAsk)));
                tmpRate.put("Bid",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateBid)));
                tmpRate.put("Balance",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateBalance)));
                //Log.d("MyDebug",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateName)));
            }
        }
    }
    rs.close();
    db.close();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(tmpRate);
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
    RowAAdapter rowAAdapter = new RowAAdapter(getActivity(),jsonArray);
    lvMarkets.setAdapter(rowAAdapter);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

The problem is that when i load this function, it only shows the last data.

I hope you can help me with my problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: why're you using the hashmap, you can put the values directly into the jsonObject like you're putting in the hashmap

Comment: how? but it think it just the same and i wanted it to be a jsonarray because the adapter is set as JSONArray

Comment: `if(rs.moveToFirst())
        {
            while(rs.moveToNext())
            {/*..*/}}` == data without first row ...

Comment: correct observation @Selvin

Comment: @AshishRanjan Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the values directly into the jsonObject instead of adding it to the hashmap like this :

```
public void LoadMarkets()
{


    RateDb db = new RateDb(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Cursor rs = db.getData();
    if(rs!=null && rs.getCount()>0)
    {
        if(rs.moveToFirst())
        {
            while(rs.moveToNext())
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("rateID",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateID)));
                jsonObject.put("Name",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateName)));
                jsonObject.put("Rate",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateRate)));
                jsonObject.put("Date",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateDate)));
                jsonObject.put("Time",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateTime)));
                jsonObject.put("Ask",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateAsk)));
                jsonObject.put("Bid",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateBid)));
                jsonObject.put("Balance",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateBalance)));
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
                //Log.d("MyDebug",rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(RateDb.rateName)));
            }
        }
    }
    rs.close();
    db.close();
    RowAAdapter rowAAdapter = new RowAAdapter(getActivity(),jsonArray);
    lvMarkets.setAdapter(rowAAdapter);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

The problem with your code is that :

You're putting the `values` with `keys` `"rateID", "Name"`... etc. in the `while` loop again and again, so the previous values are being replaced with the new values and finally you've just one set of data in your hashmap. That's why you're getting only the last set of data.

Try the above code. It should work as expected.

This will work as it creates a new `JsonObject` in the loop and adds it to the jsonArray when the data is successfully added to it.